# How do I @Autowire @Component`s in an enum constructor?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, enums, autowired

Let's say, I have a class `ProviderService` with a `Map<ProviderEnum, Provider>` field. The constructor for this class is then as follows

```java
@Autowired
ProviderService(ProviderA provA, ProviderB provB, ...) {
    map.put(ProviderEnum.A, provA);
    map.put(ProviderEnum.B, provB);
    ...
}
```

`Provider` is an abstract class inheritors of which are annotated with `@Component`.
Then I realized there are at least two possibly better ways to do it:

1. Use `EnumMap` for the implementation of the `Map`. Now, I use `HashMap`.
2. Have a `Provider` field **within** `ProviderEnum` enum and remove the map from `ProviderService` entirely.

The second option seems like the cleaner solution and I started writing it like so

```java
enum ProviderEnum {
    A(/* ?WHAT DO I PUT HERE? */),
    B(/* Is it some kind of BeanFactory.getBean(ProviderB.class)? */),
    ...;

    private final Provider provider;
    
    ProviderEnum(Provider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    
    public Provider getProvider() {
        return this.provider;
    }    
}
```

However, I do not know what I should put in those constructors as it is certainly different from the usual case of using `@Autowired`.
I imagine I should look into using `BeanFactory` but then is there a way to constructor-inject it? Should I field-inject it?
Or is it better to just stick to `EnumMap`?

Comment: Enum values are implicitly static, and static state is a Bad Design Pattern. You seem to have an XY problem here: What is the intended purpose of using an enum as a discriminator?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have a collection of providers which I want to access. I could rely on a `Map<String, Provider>` but an enum seems like a much more solid option. Hence a bunch of questions at the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are static, imo a better way would be to autowire collections of a type into your service, something like this

1. Provider Interface (or how you see it) with

```java
public interface Provider {
    // This can be your differentiator
    ProviderEnum getProviderType();
    void doSomeProviderThing();    
}
```

2. In your ProviderService class, you can autowire a collection and use PostConstruct to do the rest

```
@Component
public class ProviderService {

    // This will autowire all providers as a collection
    @Autowired
    private  Collection<Provider> providers;
 
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        providers.stream().foreach( provider -> {
            // Do you mapping with provider.getProviderType() if you still see value.
            // like map.put(provider.getProviderType(), provider);
        }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: The best solution, but it's better to use constructor injection (and that lets you create a `Map<String, Provider>` at startup time).